# Adding custom dialog for local_auth Flutter

Tags: android, ios, dart, flutter, localauthentication

I was just messing around with the package [local_auth](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/local_auth) on flutter. The package works fine on both android and iOS but I couldn't find any option to add a custom dialog option in the local_auth package. Does anyone have any idea? Any help would be deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible at the moment. It is an open issue on flutter's github:

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/30601